# React Native: how to send value of TextInput in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to send value of TextInput to another screen , can someone Help me with please..
Here is my code:

```
  const [text, setText] = useState ( ' ');
  return (
<>
        <TextInput style={styles.input}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="   Type "
          placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
          //defaultValue={text}
        />
 <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
-----
```

this is my Detais Screen:

```
function DetailsScreen(  {text}) {
  return (

<View>


  <Text> Hello this is Details  Screen + { text }</Text>
</View>
   
  );
}
```

can't take any value, even made a prop

Comment: Where does `DetailsScreen` get rendered? Is it being passed the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass the parameter like below

```
 <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details',{text:text})}
      />
```

And in your details screen you should receive it like below

```
function DetailsScreen(  {route}) {
  return (
<View>
  <Text> Hello this is Details  Screen + { route.params.text }</Text>
</View>
  );
}
```

Refer the [official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Comment: oh, thank you very much , it worked ? but can i ask you a question? how route works? its like a prop?

Comment: It not like a prop, basically the object you pass as the second parameter would be in the route.params, the rendering of your component is handled by the navigation library so you dont have control over the props of that component, only way is to pass params like above.

Comment: oh, ok . i tried this techninque with my second TextInput that is numeric :           onChangeText={num => setNum(num)} , and in Details screen is like :       <Text> Hello this is Details  Screen + {route.params.num}</Text>
but no work..(

Comment: you passed like navigation.navigate('Details',{text:text,num:num})} ?